# In vue-choropleth, how to format numbers in reference chart?

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

In the below codepen, reference chart is showing numbers overlapped as numbers are huge.
https://codepen.io/satishvarada/pen/wvQOxKe

How to format them and show in K/M/B format for readability?

https://github.com/voluntadpear/vue-choropleth/tree/master is the repo.

````
<l-map :center="[-23.752961, -57.854357]" :zoom="6" style="height: 500px;" :options="mapOptions">
                <l-choropleth-layer :data="pyDepartmentsData" title-key="department_name" id-key="department_id" :value="value" 
                :extra-values="extraValues" geojson-id-key="dpto" :geojson="geojson" :color-scale="colorScale">
                    <template slot-scope="props">
                            <l-info-control :item="props.currentItem" :unit="props.unit" title="Department" placeholder="Hover over a department" position="topright">
                            </l-info-control>
                            <l-reference-chart title="Girls school enrolment" :color-scale="colorScale" :min="props.min" :max="props.max" position="topleft">
                            </l-reference-chart>
                    </template>
                </l-choropleth-layer>
        </l-map>
    ```
````